# Joshua Bloch builder pattern - a good idea when concerned about thread safety?

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface, thread-safety, builder

I am considering using the builder pattern described by Joshua Bloch mentioned [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2). 
I have a class which displays an Alert message and will be used by numerous applications. 
It can have a large number of varied options like, line1, btn txt, title, line2, timeout etc.

I like the idea of chaining the object construction with setters, but really all the app has to do after the construction is to display this alert.

Since the object created is immutable, they will have to create multiple ones for different scenarios. 
All calls to display these alerts are asynchronous.

Is this pattern a good idea or is better to just have static methods in the class, keep it stateless and take all the parameters in the method itself.

Comment: Properly applied, the builder pattern is thread safe.

Comment: If you're worried about performance or memory usage, don't be. You'll create many different immutable objects, but they will be cleaned up by the garbage collector quickly, or the JIT compiler might even to decide to not allocate them on the heap at all. 

Object creation is considered cheap these days.

Comment: It is often relatively straightforward to keep mutable builder objects thread confined (it is the usual case that an immutable object is built by only one thread, even if it is subsequently used by many) and, therefore, thread safe.  If you create an instance of a builder locally, but then never publish its reference, it is always thread safe (and this is usually how it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you link mentions it. One of the usecases of the builder pattern is to create a complex *immutable* object. One you don't want to write a huge constructor for because there are just too many parameters.

While the builder is mutable and has setters like a bean - is therefore not threadsafe - the resulting object you build is. Objects that don't have mutable state can be shared across as many threads as you wish. Nothing can modify them, so nothing can read inconsistent state.

-> safe if you don't share the builder across threads and the resulting object is threadsafe. Threadsafety of the resulting object is by the way totally independent from the way you create it.

> Is this pattern a good idea or is better to just have static methods in the class, keep it stateless and take all the parameters in the method itself.

Depends on how complex the creation of the object is. Stateless is always good but with just `static` methods, how would you pass some sort of configuration for the alert? There must be some state somewhere to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems overly complex to use a builder for such a utility method.  A series of static methods with apt overload signatures would do the trick fine. Not "oh my god the sky is collapsing" complexity, granted, but most consumers might consider statics "easier".

Of course, if you find yourself needing 4 overloads with (String, String, String), things change I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Using the builder pattern in a concurrent system is perfectly fine.

The key decision factors are the number of parameters, and how many valid permutations of exist.